# WPF Data Binding and List Item Access

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a button click method that populates a list, which in turn feeds a ListBox control. The  method and WPF result are shown here:

```
     private void checkForThirdPartyUpdatesButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckforThirdPartyUpdatesButton.IsEnabled = false;


        worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {
            MainEntry.checkFor3PUpdates();

        };

        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
        {

            if (comparisonStateView.Count == 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in RegScan_ThirdParty.comparisonListWithState)
                {
                    comparisonStateView.Add(item);
                }
            }

            ThirdPartyListBox.DataContext = comparisonStateView;

            CheckforThirdPartyUpdatesButton.IsEnabled = true;

        };

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

[image]

I'm trying to add code that checks for the number of used deferrals and disables the "Postpone" button in each listbox item where that criteria is matched. This adjusted code performs the logic I want, but it disables the wrong button:

```
    private void checkForThirdPartyUpdatesButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckforThirdPartyUpdatesButton.IsEnabled = false;


        worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {
            MainEntry.checkFor3PUpdates();

        };

        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
        {

            if (comparisonStateView.Count == 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in RegScan_ThirdParty.comparisonListWithState)
                {
                    comparisonStateView.Add(item);
                }
            }

            ThirdPartyListBox.DataContext = comparisonStateView;

            CheckforThirdPartyUpdatesButton.IsEnabled = true;

            foreach (var rowItem in comparisonStateView)
            {
                if (rowItem.Item3.UsedDeferrals >= rowItem.Item2.MaxDefferals)
                {
                    Button ThirdPartyPostponeButton = sender as Button;
                    ThirdPartyPostponeButton.IsEnabled = false;
                }

            }

        };

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Any thoughts on how I can achieve the desired effect? I'm including a final code snippet that shows how the "Postpone" button is bound and utilized just in case it helps:

```
   private void postponeThirdPartyUpdatesButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var context = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as Tuple<RegScan_ThirdParty.InstalledApplicationFromRegistryScan, RegScan_ThirdParty.ManifestRequiredApplication, RegScan_ThirdParty.RequiredApplicationState>;

        foreach (var rowItem in comparisonStateView)
        {
            if (rowItem.Item1.Name == context.Item1.Name)
            {
                comparisonStateView.Remove(rowItem);
                break;
            }

        }

        Button ThirdPartyPostponeButton = sender as Button;
        ThirdPartyPostponeButton.IsEnabled = false;

        if (context != null)
        {
            RegScan_ThirdParty.registryApplicationPostponeWorkflow(context);
        }

        ThirdPartyPostponeButton.IsEnabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying that the Postpone button should be disabled and not the Third Party postpone button?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I can see that you are just setting the `IsEnabled` to the `ThirdPartyPostponeButton`? Where is your code to disable the postpone button?

Comment: It's in the 2nd posted code block: `ThirdPartyPostponeButton.IsEnabled = false;`

Comment: I wanna see your view